# fl chart How to set the bottom title with date and interval by time?

Tags: flutter

I try to use fl chart to make a chart with some data (image 1). I want to set the bottom title with the date and interval by time. How can I set the date or time in the bottom title?

```
LineChart(
        LineChartData(
          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
            bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(
                showTitles: true,
                interval: 1,
              )
            ),
            rightTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(
                showTitles: false
              )
            ),
            topTitles: AxisTitles(
              sideTitles: SideTitles(
                showTitles: false
              )
            )
          ),
          borderData: FlBorderData(show: true),
          lineBarsData: [
            LineChartBarData(
              spots: series,
              isCurved: false,
              color: tPrimaryColor,
              barWidth: 4,
              isStrokeCapRound: true,
              dotData: const FlDotData(show: true),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image: Current chart]
[image]

Comment: I found that syncfusion_flutter_charts can convert data to charts. Which one can set the bottom title with the date and interval by time syncfusion_flutter_charts or fl_chart?

Answer (score 0):

Import the necessary packages: Make sure you have imported the fl_chart package in your Flutter project. You can do this by adding fl_chart to your pubspec.yaml file and running flutter pub get.

Set up your chart data: Before customizing the axis, ensure that you have set up your chart data. This includes defining your data points and configuring your chart settings.

Customize the bottom axis: Use the FlTitlesData class to customize the titles along the bottom axis. You can specify the interval, format, and other properties of the titles.

```
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';

class MyChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<double> data; // Your data points
  final List<String> dates; // Your dates corresponding to the data points

  MyChart({required this.data, required this.dates});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LineChart(
      LineChartData(
        // Your chart data configuration here
        // e.g., minX, maxX, minY, maxY, lineBarsData, etc
        titlesData: FlTitlesData(
          bottomTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            reservedSize: 22,
            getTextStyles: (context, value) => const TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff72719b),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
            getTitles: (value) {
              // Here you can customize the bottom titles
              // For example, if your 'dates' list contains date strings
              // corresponding to each data point, you can return them here
              // based on the index of the value.

              // Example:
              // value will be the double value of your data point
              // Convert it to an integer index
              final index = value.toInt();
              // Ensure the index is within the range of your 'dates' list
              if (index >= 0 && index < dates.length) {
                // Return the corresponding date string
                return dates[index];
              }
              // If the index is out of range, return an empty string
              return '';
            },
            margin: 8,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think your code is outdated. The getTextStyles and getTitles properties are not in the fl chart package.